# Exporting contact group in GMail (incorrectly) exports all groups for those contacts

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, export

Using the instructions provided by Google (and by other stackexchangers), it is quite easy to export a group of contacts (select the radio button for it during export). However, when I import that same group elsewhere, Gmail re-creates all of the other groups that those same group-members were in. When you look at the csv file that Google creates, it's easy to see why:

Taylor Fred,Fred,,Taylor,,,,,,,F.T.,,,,,,,,,,,,Personal,,,,* My Contacts ::: Seminar ::: Members,* Other,ftaylor@domain.com,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

You can see in this (de-identified) list that it includes both the group I exported (Members) and another contact group (Seminar). When I import it in a another Gmail account, Gmail (in error) creates all of the "other" groups that people like Fred Taylor are in (like Seminar) even though all I wanted was "Members". So, my question is...is this a bug or some kind of feature? It seems like a bug to me. Why would I want information about groups other than the one I'm specifically importing? My followup is...does anyone know how to work around this? Other than opening the CSV and doing some kind of find/replace to get rid of the extraneous group info.